# Deleting large sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm stuck in unique situation. In my app, I have local database. Somehow one of the tables got filled with junk data and database grew massively large. By the time I came to know, size was over 1 gb. So I kept getting database locked exception as reading that junk rows on that table was very very slow. After debugging, I figured out which table it was and now I want to delete it (either drop whole table or delete all rows) but whenever I perform any operation on that table, database gets locked and ANR happens. So I'm not sure how to get rid of that table. I can't uninstall app.

Note that I'm using GreenDao in my android app.

I've tried following things

```
1) DROP TABLE mytable;
2) DELETE FROM mytable;
3) DaoSession.getMyDao().deleteAll(); // this is a greedao method but it internally performs 2nd query I mentioned I think
```

In all the cases. It is just producing ANR.and app database gets locked.

Edit: I tried it in separate thread also, It just avoided ANR but did not drop table and database was still locked.

After lock I get this whenever other thread tried to write to db which is obvious.

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/myapp/databases/mydb.db'.
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
 #################################################################
 Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY)
 Caused By : The database file is locked.
 (database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)
 #################################################################
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1000)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:704)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:385)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:359)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:248)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:199)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:514)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:934)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:895)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:708)
 at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:646)
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:283)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
 at com.intouchapp.database.IntouchDb.getNewReadableDaoSesssion(IntouchDb.java:80)
 at com.intouchapp.models.ActivityLogsDb.getCursorOfAllResults(ActivityLogsDb.java:298)
 at com.intouchapp.services.ActivityLogsDbInsertionService.onHandleIntent(ActivityLogsDbInsertionService.java:73)
 at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Also I get this too,

```
The connection pool for database '+data+user+0+myapp+databases+mydb' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 2262 (SyncAdapterThread-1) with flags 0x2 for 12.0060005 seconds.
Connections: 1 active, 0 idle, 0 available.

Requests in progress:
executeForChangedRowCount started 12645ms ago - running, sql="DELETE FROM 'mytable'"
```

This clearly states that It is not able to execute `"DELETE FROM 'mytable'"` this particular query hence the lock.

Comment: ANR occurs when you are doing long, time comsuming operation in the **main UI** thread, so in order to avoid ANR you have to do that in the background

Comment: Yeah right, I tried in separate thread also. but it just avoided ANR. no luck with deleting table.

Comment: so what was the stacktrace?

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999433/deletion-of-rows-in-table-cause-locks) is related to your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deletion of rows in table cause LOCKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999433/deletion-of-rows-in-table-cause-locks)

Comment: How about create similar DB and then copy data from other tables, then rename DB files to swap the large table out? Assuming the issue is just when accessing the large table.

Comment: @MikeT That sounds like a good idea but then size of that huge table ( more than a gb) will add up in app's total size even though we are not using that db. Something I can't afford.

Comment: @Apr444 sorry after swapping it out testing etc, delete it (the file).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite locks database when it is used to write operation.
You should take care about some points regarding this :-

- DataBase operation should use in another Thread not in UI Thread.
- Make a single instance of SQLiteOpenHelper class
- close all the instances of database after finishing task
- always use endTransaction()
- close all instance of database in finally block